# Responsive images with fixed height CSS

Tags: css, responsive-design, responsive

I want to fit an image in a div which has a fixed height and the image should expand to 100% without messing with the aspect ratio and also want the image to be responsive. I tried this,

```
img{
    height:500px;
    width:100%;
  }
```

This messes the aspect ratio. How can I fix that?

Comment: Questions seeking help (**"why isn't/how to make this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and _the **shortest code necessary to reproduce it** in the question itself_. See: How to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do it with CSS [`object-fit`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit):

```
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

Or `contain` depends on your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can set width and height using VW (view width), this means that your image will have width and height based in the width of screen

> img{
>       height:50vw;
>       width:100vw; }

in this example your image will have 100% width and 50% of heigth based in the width